# Why do I get Declare Identifier and many other errors in PL SQL package?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I am trying to create a PL SQL package in Toad. I click on 'compile as script'. It says package created but with compilation errors; I get this huge list of errors but I wanna start from the first one.

Here is the first few lines of my code (the package is huge and obviously don't want to post all of it)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE cop_cow_scripts AS
TYPE arr_claims_t IS VARRAY(15000) OF VARCHAR2(10);
TYPE arr_sql_t IS VARRAY(500) OF VARCHAR2(1000);

-- declaring procedure that will call COP_DATALOAD_V2 and COW_DATALOAD
PROCEDURE COP_COW_DATALOAD_V2(claims_array arr_claims_t, sql_array arr_sql_t);

END cop_cow_scripts;


CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY cop_cow_scripts AS


sql_statments arr_sql := arr_sql();--initialize a empty lis
```

---

```
   /*                    PROCEDURE AND VARIABLE 
                    INITILIZATION FOR  COW_DATALOAD_V2
  /***************************************************************************/
```

---

```
--*********** PUT YOUR LIST OF CERTS BELOW ******************

v_certList arr_claims := arr_claims('3803617642', '3805126441', '3876849047'
, '3873116383', '3873306670', '3878876718'); 





 --COP VARIABLES---
new_copId number; --NEW COP ID 
prod_copId number; --PROD COP ID
new_seq_id number; --NEW SEQ ID  
suppl_count number; --supplemental count

v_SQL varchar2(7000);
v_certLst varchar2(2000);
n_success NUMBER := 0; --Count of success found
n_total NUMBER := 0; --Total Records proccessed
n_suppl NUMBER := 0; --Total Records proccessed
n_orders NUMBER := 0; --Total lmso orders downloaded


/*cop procedure*/
PROCEDURE COP_DATALOAD_V2(arr_claims arr_claims_t, arr_sql arr_sql_t)
IS
```

after this I define my first procedure.

The two main kinds of errors I am getting are these: 
4/19    PLS-00201: identifier 'ARR_SQL' must be declared
4/19    PL/SQL: Item ignored
12/16   PLS-00201: identifier 'ARR_CLAIMS' must be declared
12/16   PL/SQL: Item ignored
42/14   PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is incomplete or malformed

... and so on.

I am very new to pl sql. I am not even sure what the 4/19 or 12/16 mean as they do not seem to be corresponding the line number.

What am I doing wrong in making my package?

Comment: In your package spec, you defined types of `arr_claims_t` and `arr_sql_t`. Looks like in your body you are trying to use types `arr_claims` and `arr_sql`. Are those particular types defined anywhere (for example, as global types, e.g. `create type arr_sql ...`, or as a type in the package body/spec?

Comment: You are right. I feel dumb now. Can you help me with how to interpret the errors? Which number shows the line number? Is there a debugger or something of the sort in TOAD for better viewing? Thank you again!

Comment: `4/19` refers to line 4, column 19 in the package source, remembering that the line numbering starts from the `PACKAGE` or `PACKAGE BODY` line. In your case, the errors are in the package body, so you have to count from the `PACKAGE BODY` line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems simply that you declared `sql_statments` and `v_certList` variables with wrong type (missing '`_t`'):

Correct declaration is:

```
sql_statments arr_sql_t := arr_sql_t();--initialize a empty lis 

v_certList arr_claims_t := arr_claims_t('3803617642', '3805126441', '3876849047'
, '3873116383', '3873306670', '3878876718');
```

Answer (score 1):

It is likely that arr_claims_t is a type that your user does not have the execute privilege on.  When Oracle tries to parse your procedure this type is not known to your user so you get the errors you see.

As a user with DBA privileges run from your GUI client like SQL Developer or Toad or from the SQLPlus command line

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON arr_claims_t to <YourUser>;
GRANT EXECUTE ON arr_sql_t to <YourUser>;
```